# Riesz Representation Theorem for Functional on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $f \in H^*$. Then there is unique $y \in H$ such that $$ f(x)= \langle x,y \rangle$$ for all $x\in H. $

In the proof of this, first we use projection theorem and express $H$ as direct sum of null space of functional and it's orthogonal complement.

Then to find the value of $y$ we take non zero element say $z$ from orthogonal complement of null space of functional and we can show that the required candidate of $y$ is some scalar multiple of $z$. In particular $y=\frac{f(z)z}{||z||^2}.$

My doubt is here $y$ is dependent on choice of $z$ so if we choose another element say $z^1$ then $y$ also varies according to this, so there are more than one value for fix $f(x)$.

Can anyone explain it.

Thank you.

Comment: You should split your reasoning into two steps. First existence and then uniqueness. You say that $y$ depends on the choice of $z$. But for existence this is fine, it is not allowed to depend on $x$, but this is fine as $z$ is just in the orthogonal complement of the null space of $f$ (ie does not depend on a particular $x$). What you should do, is to verify that this choice of $y$ does what we want, namely $f(x)=\langle x, y \rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

The uniqueness statement can easily be proven.
Let's assume we have elements $y,y'$ such that $f(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$ and $f(x)=\langle x,y'\rangle$ holds true for all $x \in H$.
This implies $\langle x,y-y'\rangle=0$ for all $x \in H$.

Then, it particular it must hold for $x :=y-y'$ which implies $y=y'$.

I agree that is not clear in the first place that $y$ is independent of the choice of $z$ but we can show it this way.
I am not sure whether there is way to see this differently.